Set Cell to Excel File Info Properties
I would like to set the excel file info properties and then reference the value in a cell.
First: I want to set the "Tag" to "00"
Next: I want worksheet cell A1 to reference the tag and show "00"
Is this possible?

If there is no way to directly reference from within the cell, perhaps I can set the cell upon Workbook_Open()?

Did you do some google search? Post your codes that you have tried.

I was first trying to do this without VBA.  For example, you can reference the file name in the header or in a cell. I was hoping that you could do that same with the file properties.

You need VBA. In short:
Code to set tags:
Sub SetYourTags()

    ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(4) = "00"

End Sub

Code to show tags in A1:
Sub DisplayYourTags()

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(4)

End Sub

And yes, you can put it in Workbook_Open():
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(4)
End Sub

